# What is a Scientific Word™

Tags: pattern, english, word-property

If a word has a certain property, I call it a Scientific Word™.

In each of the short, unrelated sentences below, only one of the choices is a Scientific Word™.

The sentences do not affect whether a word is a Scientific Word™. Case, font, and letter/word appearance do not matter.

> 1. The child's mother gave him a **(apple/banana)** as a healthy snack.
> 2. When queried with the question about a raise, Dave's boss said **(no/yes)**.
> 3. Billy's breakfast consisted of **(bacon/beans)**, eggs, and toast.
> 4. The snake's sharp fangs contained a deadly **(poison/venom)** ready to be inserted into your bloodstream at the slightest movement.
> 5. Jerry's computer had gotten infected with (a) **(virus/malware)**.
> 6. The soldier died out in **(war/battle)**.
> 7. After Riley had died so many times on his video game, he was filled with **(anger/rage)**.
> 8. The same series of events had happened years **(ago/before)**, and the result was not good.
> 9. Joe has such a smart **(brain/mind)**.
> 10. To be nice, Sarah offered her umbrella to an old **(lady/woman)**.

**What makes a word a Scientific Word™?**

Comment: You said that "Case, font, and letter/word appearance do not matter." However, time matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a Scientific Word™ is one that

> that scientists around the world can use without any ambiguity, simply because these words are composed entirely from the symbols of elements in the periodic table.

1.

> Ba Na Na (Barium Sodium Sodium)

2.

> No (Nobelium)

3.

> Ba Co N (Barium Cobalt Nitrogen)

4.

> Po I S O N (Polonium Iodine Sulphur Oxygen Nitrogen)

5.

> V I Ru S (Vanadium Iodine Rubidium Sulphur)

6.

> W Ar (Tungsten Argon)

7.

> Ra Ge (Radium Germanium)

8.

> Ag O (Silver Oxygen)

9.

> B Ra In (Boron Radium Indium)

10.

> La Dy (Lanthanum Dyprosium)

All other words do not follow this Scientific Rule (patent pending).

Comment: Fill in the rest of the words and you're accepted :D

Comment: @TroyAndAbed You will forget that mistake ever happened. *uses Jedi trick* now delete your comment...

Comment: @TroyAndAbed ham was actually a typo. I had meant to put in beans after but forgot to fix it.